# Integrated Windows Authentication breaks File.Exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I have run into the wierdest issue, and I'm hoping some ASP.NET expert can give me some clues as to what is going on.

I have an ASP.NET Website running on IIS 6.0. On it, I have an .asmx webservice. In the .asmx webservice, I use `System.IO.File.Exists()` to check if a file exists on a network share. The site uses Impersonation.

Here's the massive kicker: If I set IIS to run the site using Basic Authentication, the File.Exists line returns True. If I set it to Integrated Windows Authentication, it returns False. I change nothing else, i can change back and forth and the exact same thing happens. I'm logging some information before the call to `File.Exists()` and indeed, both `User.Identity.Name` and `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` return the exact same name regardless of setting (my own account which obviously has access to the files I'm looking for).

I would post things I've tried but honestly, what can you try in this situation, where one setting which shouldn't affect the issue is the problem. I have tried turning impersonation off, and that also makes the `File.Exists()` call return True (which is blowing my mind since my own user has far higher permissions than the account running the appPool).

Any ideas what I can look into to get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK what is happening is that the server is not able to ***delegate*** the authentication. That is, it cannot act on behalf of the user to another server, only to itself.

Delegation is not a problem for Basic authentication because the server knows your password (because you told it as part of the basic authentication), so it can perform authentication to the remote computer.

If you are in an Active Directory/Kerberos environment, you must configure the server to be **trusted for delegation**. I have never had to do this so I am not sure exactly how, but it is a matter of configuration, not programming. You may have to configure the Server machine account, or the IIS identity or both, depending on your configuration.

See here for some references:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739474(v=WS.10).aspx

If you are *not* in a Kerberos environment, you must either use basic authentication, or get the password from the user in some other way, and call `LogonUser` yourself to impersonate the user. If Basic authentication is used or a clear-text password is used in any other way, you must of course use HTTPS/TLS for security.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't set up this kind of delegation, so we have to run with Basic Authentication, which at least does solve the File.Exists issue. Sadly, the background issue is that I can't call a webservice on the other server (same server that has the file share), because I get 401 Unauthorized. Unfortunately, basic authentication is not solving that issue, even though it looks like a delegation issue as well.

Comment: without Kerberos delegatation you cannot pass your credentials to another IIS server. This is the limitation of IIS, also known as the double hop issue.

Comment: @tobberoth, you can find out the password in a Basic authentication session as it is one of the session variables. That should enable you to set up an explicit basic-auth connection to the other web service.

Comment: @Ben Yeah, that's a solution I used before, which is a nice solution in situations where both sites are exclusively basic auth. An update on my issue though, I got it working and my only guess as to why it's working is that if you go from basic on the SOURCE to Integrated windows on the TARGET, .UseDefaultCredentials simply work. Basic to Basic and Int. Windows To Int. Windows does not.